# Translate a few words in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, translate

I currently am making a wordpress site where my customer can enter the title of a post and in my theme I want to translate the title of the post into Italian, but only the title, and I would like to do it in my theme. I tried using GTranslate, but my guess is that no longer works because Google now charges for that api.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shame Google Translate API is not free anymore but it's still the best I've used.

There are some free alternatives including Microsoft's translation service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512404.aspx